# Why does python specify IPv4 or IPv6 with SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_DGRAM when it also accepts `proto` in the instantiation of socket objects?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Why does python specify IPv4 or IPv6 with `SOCK_STREAM` or `SOCK_DGRAM` when it also accepts protocol number arguments in the instantiation of the socket object (nrs 4 and 41 ,see  [list of protocol numbers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xml))? (as `proto` in `socket.socket([family[, type[, proto]]])`) Doesn't that make the `family` argument useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proto` in this context refers to the Layer 4 (L4) protocol to use. Most likely this will be `IPPROTO_TCP` (TCP) or `IPPROTO_UDP` (UDP). In practice it's unlikely you will need to pass these parameters explicitly very often, as for IP generally `SOCK_STREAM` implies TCP and `SOCK_DGRAM` implies UDP.

It could come in handy for instance, however, if say you wanted to implement ICMP support in your program using raw sockets. Then you'd pass `SOCK_RAW` and `IPPROTO_ICMP`. Also, keep in mind this is based on the Berkeley sockets API which is designed to handle much more than just IP networking (take a look at all the other `AF_*` from the `socket` module to get an idea of what it supports).

In contrast, IPv4/IPv6 is a Layer 3 (L3) protocol and works independently from TCP/UDP.

EDIT:

As to why you see IPv4/IPv6 encapsulation in that list, it's to support protocols like [IP in IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_in_IP) or [6in4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6in4).  It's not likely you will deal directly with these mechanisms in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Number 4 and 41 in protocol list you linked to clearly state "IPv4 encapsulation" and "IPv6 encapsulation"  You would use IPv4 with IPV6 encapsulation for example to generate packet which are then de-capsulated (unless that's not actually a word) upstream e.g. at an IPv6 over IPv4 tunnel